# Problems generating bundle with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, requirejs, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I have a Typescript project:

```
myproject
 |
 +-src (folder)
 |  |
 |  +-main.ts
 |  +-stringHandler.ts
 |  +-disposable.ts
 +-out (folder)
 |  |
 |  +-...
 +-Gruntfile.js
```

In my Grunt configuration I have a 2-step task which compiles all `.ts` files in `myproject/src/` and generates corresponding `.js` files into `myproject/out/`. So after the first step of the task is complete, I have the following:

```
myproject
 |
 +-out (folder)
    |
    +-main.js
    +-stringHandler.js
    +-disposable.js
```

#### Bundling

The second step of the task is [generating bundle file](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-bundles) `myproject.js`. I am using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) for this purpose.

I have installed [grunt-contrib-requirejs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs). The `Gruntfile.js` file handling the bundling task is as follows (showing only relevant parts in the file):

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  var config = {
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    requirejs: {
      compile: {
        options: {
          baseUrl: "out",
          bundles: {
            'myproject': ['main', 'stringHandler', 'disposable']
          },
          out: 'out/myproject.js'
        }
      }
    }
  };
  grunt.initConfig(config);
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['compile', 'requirejs']);
};
```

When Grunt reaches `requirejs`, after successfully compiling the project, I get the following error:

> Running "requirejs:compile" (requirejs) task { [Error: Error: Missing
>   either a "name", "include" or "modules" option
>       at Function.build.createConfig (C:\Users\myuser\Documents\myproject\node_modules\grunt-contrib-requirejs\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:29567:19)
>   ]   originalError: [Error: Missing either a "name", "include" or
>   "modules" option] }

I can understand there are missing parameters, but when I use `name` I get other errors. I guess there must be something wrong at a more generic level. What is the correct configuration format? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This assumes `main.ts` is your application's entry point and that it contains a `require.config` section with your application dependencies (libraries and shims).

First, move the `require.config` section out of `main.ts` and into its own file, `config.ts`. Leave the application bootstrap code in `main.ts`.

Then determine where you want this optimized application code deployed. Let's assume it is to a directory named `build`, which is parallel to your `src` and `out` folders.

Update you Gruntfile to reflect this configuration:

```
requirejs: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            baseUrl: "out",
            mainConfigFile: "out/config.js",
            modules: [
                { name: "main" }
            ],
            dir: "build",
            optimize: "none" // skip compression while debugging
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about each of these config options at http://requirejs.org/ but here's the basic rundown:

- `baseUrl`: Where the source JS code lives.
- `mainConfigFile`: Points to the config object mentioned above. It tells the plugin where the dependencies live. This obviates the need to specify and manually update the list of dependencies in two places.
- `modules`: Is an array of application bootstraps. In this case a list of one, `main.js`.
- `dir`: Where the optimized application will be generated. Note that your dependencies will also be copied here.
- `optimize`: I left this off so you can easily debug the resulting app under `./build`. Remove it when you're happy and the plugin will optimize (compress and munge) your build files.